# VB.NET - Single class, multiple purposes?

Tags: vb.net, design-patterns

Please take a look at the class and type below:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class c1

    Dim PersonID As Integer

    Public Sub New(ByVal Person As Person)
        PersonID = Person.PersonID
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Private Sub SingleDelete()
        Dim objCommand As SqlCommand
        Dim objCon As SqlConnection
        Try
            Dim _ConString As String = "Data Source=IANSCOMPUTER;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
            objCon = New SqlConnection(_ConString)
            objCommand = New SqlCommand("Delete FROM Person were id=" & PersonID)
                objCommand.Connection = objCon
                objCon.Open()
                objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        Finally

        End Try
    End Sub

        Private Sub MassDelete(ByVal listPerson As List(Of Person))
            Dim objCommand As SqlCommand
            Dim objCon As SqlConnection
            Try
                Dim _ConString As String = "Data Source=IANSCOMPUTER;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
                objCon = New SqlConnection(_ConString)
                For Each Person In listPerson
                objCommand = New SqlCommand("Delete FROM Person were id=" & Person.PersonID)
                objCommand.Connection = objCon
                    objCon.Open()
                    objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Next
            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw
            Finally

            End Try
        End Sub
    End Class

Public Class Person
    Public PersonID As String
End Class
```

There are two uses for this class:

```
1) Call the constructor with a Person argument.  Then call SingleDelete i.e. delete one person.
2) Call the zero argument constructor.  Then call multiple delete i.e. delete many persons (all persons in the list are deleted)
```

Does this break SOLID principles? The class has two purposes in my mind.  The PersonID instance variable is not used if the zero argument constructor is used.

I wander if I am overthinking this.

Comment: Maybe. I think you can fold these into a single case if you add the WHERE clause to the command string based on whether PersonID is null.

Comment: Off topic, if this is the whole code, you're not closing your connection.

Comment: @Jack Pettinger,thanks.  I wrap always use USING statements for disposable objects in a production environment.  I missed them off the code above for speed.  +1 anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say yes: it breaks SRP.

Here's why:  the class represents two things: a person, and a collection of people.  It's basically a utility or manager class, rather than a class that identifies with a particular domain object.

However, this may not matter.  Repository classes typically do just this; they have methods for working with both individual objects and collections of the same object.  As with all things in software development, whether you take this approach or not is determined by what best meets your needs.

It would probably be a better design if the "mode" of the class didn't change depending on the way the constructor is called.  It's not necessary; if you want to delete multiple persons, you can just provide an ordinary method that takes a collection of people ID's as a parameter.

Comment: That was my thought i.e. it breaks SRP. +1.  However, atw13 raises a very good point below in my view i.e. MassDelete should be a shared function (then no constructor would be needed for the mass delete).  Do you still think it breaks SRP with this is mind?

Comment: @w0051977: That's what I mean by an "ordinary method."  Methods in repositories are typically not static; I only use static methods for operations that don't touch external state.  But a static method would probably be OK for this.

Comment: Thanks, therefore if I made MultipleDelete a shared method and removed the zero arguement constructor, then it is more SRP compliant? I realise this is down to your interpretation but it is useful to get another point of view.

Comment: If you want to provide the information about which people are going to get deleted, you can still have two constructors for convenience, but there should be only one delete method: **`Delete()`**  Or, you can just have one or more ordinary (Shared, if you like) Delete methods which you pass the Person ID's to, and not bother with the special constructors.  Does that make sense?

Comment: In other words, pass the Person ID info in through the constructors, or pass it through the method calls, but don't do both in the same class.

Comment: I believe I can use what you have suggested to meet my requirements.  Is it bad practice to use a Shared function in a class where the Shared function contains a reference to the class where it is contained? For example. a class c1 contains a Shared function called delete and within delete there is a reference and an instance of c1.

Comment: If you're working with an instance of anything, it does not need to be a "shared" method, *unless you're passing that instance as a parameter to the shared method.*

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Are you able to look at my other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15645475/using-objects-in-shared-functions, as it follows on from this.  If you do have a look and require more information then let me know.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you're looking for is what's known in most language as a "static" method, but I think the keyword in VB is "shared."  (Forgive me - I'm not that knowledgable in VB but I want to answer the conceptual question.)  The multi-deletion should not require instantiating a Person object - it's a thing you do to the class, not to one instance of the class.

So your Mass-delete should be a "class method" or "static method", which you'd use like this: Person.MassDelete(...), whereas your single delete would be called on a single instance, bob.delete().

Comment: +1 Agreed, mass deletion should be a `Public Shared Function` Returning a `Boolean`

Comment: I agree that the function should be shared.  +1.  Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

I say maybe. I think you can fold these into a single case if you add the WHERE clause to the command string based on whether PersonID is null. If so, this is a PersonDeleter with one purpose, to delete people.

I worry about this class deciding whether to wipe out a table's worth of data based on how it's constructed, but that's a separate concern.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure what you mean by a "single case"?