# Using objects in shared functions

Tags: vb.net, design-patterns

Please take a look at the code below:

```
    Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Person
    Private id As String
    Private name As String

    Public Function check(ByVal personid As String) As Boolean
        'Do some checks on the person to see if it is ready for deletion
    End Function

    Public Shared Sub Delete()
        Dim v As New Vehicle
        Dim p As New Person
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Vehicle
    Private vrm As String

    Public Function check(ByVal vehicleid As String) As Boolean
        'Do some checks on the vehicle to see if it is ready for deletion
    End Function

    Private Shared Sub Delete()
        Dim p As New Person
        Dim v As New Vehicle
        Dim objCommand As SqlCommand
        Dim objCon As SqlConnection
        Dim objDR As SqlDataReader
        Try
            Dim _ConString As String = "Data Source=IANSCOMPUTER;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
            objCon = New SqlConnection(_ConString)
            objCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Person were startdate < dateadd(year,-6," & Now & ")")
            objDR = objCommand.ExecuteReader
            Do While objDR.Read
                If p.check(objDR("id")) And v.check(objDR("vehicleid")) Then
                    'Execute delete statement, which deletes the person and vehicle
                End If
            Loop
            objDR.Close()
            objCommand.Connection = objCon
            objCon.Open()
            objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw
        Finally

        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```

Notice that the shared function (Person.Delete) contains references to Person and Vehicle and uses instance variables in Person and Vehicle.  Basically a check needs to be done on the Person and vehicle before the person and vehicle can be deleted.

Is it poor practice to reference Person and Vehicle from the Shared function? Is it poor practice to use instance variables in the Delete function.  The Delete function will delete thousands of persons and vehicles daily.

Comment: Your code seems incomplete.  The `Person` class doesn't seem to do anything.  What is the purpose of making the `Delete` subs shared?  Why are you catching an exception without handling it?

Comment: @Robert Harvey, thanks again.  The Delete subs are shared because they iterate through thousands of records.  On each iteration a Person object is created along with a vehicle object.  I am wandering whether to create a Person and Vehicle object or whether just to put all the logic in the shared function.

Comment: Making them shared won't help the fact that you're iterating thousands of times; those objects will still get created every time you call the method.  If you don't want to create all those SQL objects every time, create a helper class, make the objects *private members,* and instantiate them in the constructor.

Comment: @Robert Harvey, I do use an SQLHelper class in my live environment.  I also separate the business logic and data logic in layers.  The code above was just an attempt to explain my question, which I don't think I have done very well.

Comment: I wouldn't get too hung up on code coupling.  If you have to get the person out of the vehicle before you crush the car, then your program is going to need to know that.

Comment: @Robert Harvey, can you post an answer? as some of your comments were helpful and some credit is due.

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessarily a bad practice to make them shared, but if they are shared its a good practice to refactor them into their own classes. `Shared` instantly makes then global functions that, in my mind, should not contaminate the class signature.

So this would be better practice in my estimation:

```
Public Class Person
    Private id As String
    Private name As String
End Class

Public Class Vehicle
    Private vrm As String
End Class

Public Class PersonVanisher
    Public Shared Sub Delete()
        Dim v As New Vehicle
        Dim p As New Person
        ...
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function Check(personId As String) As Boolean
        ...
    End Function
End Class

Public Class VehicleCrusher
    Private Shared Sub Delete()
        Dim p As New Person
        Dim v As New Vehicle
        ...
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function Check(vehicleId As String) As Boolean
        ...
    End Function
End Class
```

People get into philosophical debates about this, but if it were my code I would not make anything shared.  I would prefer to "New up" a `VehicleCrusher` when I need it and let .NET dispose everything as soon as I'm done.

Comment: Thanks.  +1.  Do you think it is poor practice to create objects on every loop in the Delete function i.e. on every loop a new Person and Vehicle object is created.  I think I am overthinking it, personally.

Comment: Personally, i'd prefer not to have a class named `VehicleManager`.  :P  The name doesn't say much about an instance's role in things.  If it's just there to delete vehicles, i'd call it `CarCrusher`.  :)   That still seems a bit odd, though, having a class that does nothing but delete objects of another class...

Comment: @cHao, +1 for CarCrusher.  Do you agree with this answer accept for the name of the classes?

Comment: @w0051977: Just updated my comment.  Not sure i like the idea of a `VehicleManager` in general.  Even without the name, that's pretty much what it is.  It seems kinda wacky, when your `Vehicle` and `Person` types already do that to a huge degree.  (If they didn't, you wouldn't be able to just `new` one up at will and use it; you'd get one passed to you.)

Comment: OK, I agree 'Manager' is a bad name. I forgot I was on StackExchange.  LOL. I'll update the names...

Comment: @w0051977: What i mean is, although we talk about "single responsibility" and all that, an object that exists solely to delete `Vehicle` objects seems just a bit *too* narrowly focused.  Its existence all but depends on it and the `Vehicle` class sharing implementation details, which goes against the whole loose-coupling thing that SOLID aims for.

Comment: @cHao, the logic that underpins a deletion is quite complex i.e. the check functions from my original post contain code.  A deletion can be person driven or vehicle driven i.e. it is vehicle driven if there is no owner.  This is why there are classes dedicated to this.  Does this persuade you?

Comment: @w0051977: It makes a tiny bit more sense, i guess.  I'm almost certain there's a less iffy way, but i couldn't say much more without being in your position and seeing the whole picture.

Comment: @cHao, can you suggest another way? (I know this may be difficult without understanding the problem domain).  Perhaps write an answer so that I can give some credit?

Comment: @w0051977: Right now, `Person` for example seems rather torn about whether it represents an entity, a table, a process, or a namespace for functions.  It needs to decide.  If it's an entity, then `check` shouldn't take an ID; it should be checking the instance, and everything it needs should already be defined in the class.  If it's the table, then the proper place for the `Delete` method is in that class.  (Oh, and it should have a less entity'ish name, like `Persons`.)  JMNSHO.  If it's a process or namespace, then eh.  Do what you want, it's not OO anyway.  :)

Comment: @cHao ,what is the difference between an entity and a table (in the context of your last comment).  Last question I promise.

Comment: @w0051977: Pretty similar to the difference between, say, a `String` and a `List(of String)`.  One represents the actual thing, and the other represents/manages a *collection* of those things, which in your case are stored in a database table.

Comment: @cHao, are these terms from ORM? What is a "process"? Is an entity a collection?

Comment: @w0051977: They don't *come* from ORM, but some of them apply there.  An entity is the actual thing.  A table is the collection.  A "process" has nothing to do with any of that; it's the procedure, the steps for mucking around with the data, without any pretense of OOness.

Comment: @cHao, Last question (I promise).  In your comment 54 minutes ago you say: "If it's the table, then the proper place for the Delete method is in that class".  If the delete method is part of the person class then would you use local variables for the person state (remember there will be many loops) or instance variables.

Comment: I wasn't focused on the Check() methods, but cHao is a wise man; they are poorly designed as they stand in my current answer. The ID arguments should be removed, or the methods themselves.  My guess (without seeing all the code) is that they belong in the manager classes, I'll move them there...